# Have a bluff click on my website when it first loads

Tags: jquery, lazy-loading

```
$(function callLazyLoad(){
$(window).bind("resize click scroll", function(event) {
      $('img.lazy').lazyload();
  });
```

});

Hi, i created the above codes to allow the images to load when the website is being resized, clicked or scrolled. However, i first enter the website, the images will only be loaded when i click, scroll or resize the website. How do i make the images load by default. I cannot change the above codes because i will need it to load only when it's resized, clicked or scrolled for another page.

Is there any way i can let the images load by default on my home page, like perhaps, have a fake call to click the website? Please help!

Comment: Is there any reason you can't call `$('img.lazy').lazyload();` on document.ready?

Answer (score 0):

1) Just invoke lazy load on document ready

```
     $(function callLazyLoad(){
        $(window).bind("resize click scroll", function(event) {
           $('img.lazy').lazyload();
        });
        $('img.lazy').lazyload();
     });
```

2) extract function with lazy load and invoke it and pass to bind

```
     $( function lazyLoadEventHandler() {
           $('img.lazy').lazyload();
        }

        lazyLoadEventHandler();

        function callLazyLoad(){
        $(window).bind("resize click scroll", lazyLoadEventHandler); 
     });
```